# Material-ui-next Responsive Drawer missing border

Tags: reactjs, border, material-ui

Hi I am using material ui next responsive drawer, when main content have many items drawer missing right border.

[image]

I just copyed https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/ Responsive Drawer example

Comment: Check `height` style property of `root` className

Comment: @SamLau I changed it height: '100%', but i have a same sitatuion.

Comment: You can try `100vh`

Comment: Does not changing everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a JSFiddle and I will see if I can help you. But, you can inspect the element with your browser inspector, you can try to add a `height` property in `j137` class :

**Without the property :**

[image]

**With `heigth` property**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your answer and tell me how to add height property in j137 class?

Comment: The class generate by Mui demo is different with your local className, so you will not find `j137` className in your local app. With the web inspector, you'll able to inspect the same frame as follow examples. You need to override a `div` with `style` or `className` in your code

Comment: See https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/ to override your appbar and add `height` property

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple solution. Change the height of the `root` class. It is set to `430` by default so that it fits within the demo page of the documentation.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import List from 'material-ui/List';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Hidden from 'material-ui/Hidden';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import { mailFolderListItems, otherMailFolderListItems } from './tileData';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,

    //CHANGE THIS TO WHATEVER HEIGHT e.g. '100%'

    height: 430,
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
  },
  ....
});

class ResponsiveDrawer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mobileOpen: false,
  };

  handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ mobileOpen: !this.state.mobileOpen });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;

    const drawer = (
      <div>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Divider />
        <List>{mailFolderListItems}</List>
        <Divider />
        <List>{otherMailFolderListItems}</List>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
      ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ResponsiveDrawer);
```

Comment: I changed it height: '100%', but i have a same sitatuion.

Answer (score 0):

With `height:1000px` I don't have the bug. Post your code.

[image]

Comment: Wile you dont have a scrool you cant see it. Try to add many "You think water moves fast" Typography and you can see it.